# Adding bootstrap css lets background image disappear

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a small problem adding a background image to my bootstrap site. I want the background image to be present over the whole page, so i choosed it to display at the html-tag. It's working fine, till i add the `bootstrap.min.css` file. Then my background disappear and the background stays white.

Here are my `Index.html` and my own `style.css` files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid fill">
    <div id="content">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Link Button</a>
    </div> <!-- This one wants to be 100% height -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
html {
      background-image: url('test.jpeg');
      background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
    #content {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        display: block;
        }
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .fill { 
        min-height: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

The folder structure is like that

```
Index.html
css
|
__style.css
__test.jpeg
```

Do you have any suggestions what could be the problem ?

Comment: Is the Bootstrapcss file called after or before your css file?

Comment: NVM I see now that it is

Comment: I think bootstrap is defining a background-color for the body not the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap is defining the background-color on the body, not on the html.

You can set the backgournd-image to the body, although I strongly recommand to customize your bootstrap version with less or sass rather than overwriting every css rules.